# Jquery event delegation inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><form type="submit" action=""></form></td>
</tr>
```

I want to have click event on tr but not when I click on the submit button

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I tried using `:not()` but lost.

Comment: `<form type="submit"`? `type submit`?

Comment: You need to learn HTML and JavaScript. You can attach an Event to almost any Element.

Comment: What was the selector in your not function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$("tr").on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('form[type="submit"]').length == 0) {
    console.log("clicked");
  }
})
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/3k7mpndt/)**</kbd>

If dom is dynamic

```
$(document).on("click","tr", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('form[type="submit"]').length == 0) {
    console.log("clicked");
  }
})
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/qt1nL7wr/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

your can also try.

```
$("tr").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("clicked");
});
$("form").on("click", function(e) { //this could be your submit button
  console.log("clicked form");
  return false;
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/puuhpxfd/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the default functionality of the form would be broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $tr = $("tr") ;
$tr.on("click", "form", function (e) {
    e.originalEvent.wuzformclick = true;
} );

$tr.on("click",  function (e) {
    if(! e.originalEvent.wuzformclick) {

        //do stuff 
    } 
}
```